# Assembly, how to read something from a txt?

Tags: assembly, text, file-io

I need read a phrase and then say how many times appears each letter, for example:

```
"Hello sir" 

H=1, E=1 , L=2, O=0, S=, I=1, R=1
```

But I dont know how to take the text from a txt and then use it on my assembly code.

Comment: the same way you would do it in any other language, how would you do it in some other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Test.txt"))
        {
            var str = sr.ReadToEnd();

            var charList = str.Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var chr in charList)
            {
                var count = str.Count(x => x == chr);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", chr, count));
            }
        }
```